# Decoding nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects, decoding

I need to decode object *input* to object *output* as below:

```js
let input = {
         a : 'b',
        'c.d': 'e',
        'c.f': 'g',
        'c.h.0':'i',
        'c.h.1':'j',
        'c.h.2':'k'
}

let output = {
    a : 'b',
    c: {
       d: 'e',
       f:'g',
       h: ['i', 'j', 'k']
     }
    }
```

I have this decoding function, It works well except for arrays. How can I change this function to also support array decoding, and return the above output object

```js
function assembleQueryData(input) {
  const output = {};

  const keys = Object.keys(input);

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const dots = key.split(".");

    let last = output;
    for (let j = 0; j < dots.length; j++) {
      const dot = dots[j];
      if (j >= dots.length - 1) {
        last[dot] = input[key];
      } else {
        last[dot] = last[dot] || {};
      }
      last = last[dot];
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: I have to mention that there's typo in your code in `d: 'e,`, it should be `d: 'e',`.

Comment: Is the input a string?

Comment: hey, code does not run, i had to put the object keys with `'` like: `'c.d': 'g'`, and had to replace `input.keys` by `Object.keys(input)` can you pls improve the code? you can put it as executable in your question

Comment: I have fixed the code

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = {
   a : 'b',
   'c.d': 'e',
   'c.f': 'g',
   'c.h.0': 'i',
   'c.h.1': 'j',
   'c.h.2': 'k',
   'l.m.0': 'n',
   'l.m.1': 'o',
   'l.m.2': 'p',
   'l.m.q': 'r',
}

const assembleQueryData = (input) => {
  const output = {}
  const keys = Object.keys(input)

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i]
    const dots = key.split('.')

    let parent = null;
    let last = output
    for (let j = 0; j < dots.length; j++) {
      const dot = dots[j]
      if (j >= dots.length - 1) {
        if (!/^\d+$/.test(dot) && Array.isArray(last)) {
          last = Object.fromEntries(last.map((value, i) => [i, value]));
          parent[dots[j - 1]] = last
        }
        last[dot] = input[key]
      } else {
        last[dot] = last[dot] || (/^\d+$/.test(dots[j + 1]) ? [] : {})
      }
      parent = last
      last = last[dot]
    }
  }

  return output
}

console.log(assembleQueryData(input));
```

Comment: Thanks, it woks well, but how about having 'c.h.0' , 'c.h.1' , 'c.h.2', and 'c.h.a' . I think in this case (when all the suffixes for the current key are not numbers) the code should detect it is not an array and decode it as object.

Comment: @MahsaShadi Hopefully fixed in the new variant.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is an easy way to cover all the cases in one go, in this solution we are first creating an object representation of the given input and then replacing the object with an array where ever we deem fit in Depth-first transversal, we here are also taking care of creating proper arrays.

```js
let input = {
  'a': 'b',
  'c.d': 'e',
  'c.f': 'g',
  'c.h.0': 'i',
  'c.h.1': 'j',
  'c.h.2': 'k',
  'c.k.0': 'i',
  'c.h.a': 'j',
  'c.p.0.5.c': 'j',
  'd.1': {},
  'd.1.6':'cat'
}

console.log(input)

const assembleQueryData = (input) => {
  return Object.entries(input).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    let keySet = key.split('.');
    keySet.reduce((p, k, i) => {
      if (keySet.length === (i + 1)) { p[k] = value; }
      else { p[k] = p[k] || {}; }
      return p[k]
    }, obj);
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

isObjectOrArray = (input) => {
  return Array.isArray(input) || typeof input === 'object' && input !== null;
}

// recursive array which get array if object is array
const getArrays = (input) => {
  if (!isObjectOrArray(input)) {
    return input;
  }

  let isArray =  Array.isArray(input);
  if (!isArray) {
    let isArray = !Object.keys(input).some(k => isNaN(k));
    if (isArray) {
      let len =  Math.max(...Object.keys(input))
      let arr = Array(len + 1).fill(undefined);
      input = arr.map((v, i) => input[i]);
    }
  }

  Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    input[key] = getArrays(value);
  });
  return input
}

let objOutput = assembleQueryData(input)
let output = getArrays(objOutput)
console.log(output)
```